# Syntax issue when using dynamic query

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

Query 1:

```
  SET @sql2 = 'insert into TempReport   
  select ID, max(TransactionTime),0 from  ClubTransaction with (nolock)  
  where ClubcardID in (select ClubcardID from TempCC)   
  and ClubcardTransaction.OfferID  not in (119,120,121)  
  group by ClubcardID' 
  exec (@Sql2)
```

Query 2:

```
  delcare @OfferID varchar(50)
  set   OfferID='1,112,445,'  
  SET @sql2 = 'insert into TempReport   
  select ID, max(TransactionTime),0 from  ClubTransaction with (nolock)  
  where ClubcardID in (select ClubcardID from TempCC)   
  and ClubcardTransaction.OfferID not in (Select Item From dbo.fnSplit(@OfferID,'','')   
  group by ClubcardID'    
  exec (@Sql2)
```

Query 1 works fine. In query2 I am replacing with an variable de  defined where I am passing to the function fnSplit where I split the values with comma separated.
I get an error message `Must declare the scalar variable "@OfferID"`.
Please let me know where is the issue here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put the value from outside and replace the ' by ":

Query 2:

```
  declare @OfferID varchar(50)
  set   OfferID='1,112,445,'  
  SET @sql2 = 'insert into TempReport   
  select ID, max(TransactionTime),0 from  ClubTransaction with (nolock)  
  where ClubcardID in (select ClubcardID from TempCC)   
  and ClubcardTransaction.OfferID not in (Select Item From dbo.fnSplit(' + replace(convert(varchar(4000), @OfferID), '''', '''''') + ',"","")   
  group by ClubcardID'    

  exec (@Sql2)
```

---

**Another solution** (and a better one) is to use [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)

---

Be aware that dynamic SQL is a way to make sql injections and you should avoid using it..